# flask socket io heroku timeout

Tags: javascript, flask, socket.io, connection, timeout

I have a js socket.io client that only connects to my flask socket.io when i run it locally, but it does not connect when i try through heroku. the other parts of the flask api work and run good, the only thing that does not work is socket.io connection.
Their is aconsole logs "disconnected", sometimes also a error in the console of `Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received`, even though the connection is not requested to do something.
**this is my html js socket.io client code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>socket</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Socket.IO Demo</h1>
    <button onclick="send()">sdgfhk</button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/3.0.4/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-aMGMvNYu8Ue4G+fHa359jcPb1u+ytAF+P2SCb+PxrjCdO3n3ZTxJ30zuH39rimUggmTwmh2u7wvQsDTHESnmfQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.5.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io.connect("https://onlineauctionapi.herokuapp.com/", { transports: ['websocket'] });
        socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
        });


        socket.on('join', () => {
            console.log("joined")
        });

        function send(){
            socket.emit('send',{message:"hello", room:"hello"})
        }

        socket.on('connect', () => {
            console.log("connected")
        });

        socket.on('disconnect', () => {
            console.log('disconnected');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**this is my flask socket.io server code:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*":{"origins":"*"}})
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

@app.route('/signin', methods=['POST'])
def signIn():
    return signin(request) 
# signin is a function that signs you in

@socketio.on('connect')
def on_connect():
    print("connected")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)), debug=True)
```

**this is my Procfile:**

```
web: gunicorn main:app
```

**this is my requirements.txt**

```
bidict==0.22.0
cffi==1.15.0
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.5
dnspython==2.2.1
eventlet==0.33.1
Flask==2.1.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.10
Flask-SocketIO==5.2.0
gevent==21.12.0
gevent-websocket==0.10.1
gitdb==4.0.9
GitPython==3.1.27
greenlet==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
pycparser==2.21
pymongo==4.1.1
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-dotenv==0.20.0
python-engineio==4.3.2
python-socketio==5.6.0
six==1.16.0
smmap==5.0.0
Werkzeug==2.1.2
zope.event==4.5.0
zope.interface==5.4.0
```

I tried playing around with the versions of the socket in the flask api, but it did not help. the regular requests and the socket.io requests are on the same api, and still the regular request are working, but the socket ones are not.

**these are my logs from heroku:**

```
2022-06-28T15:41:18.631530+00:00 app[web.1]: connected
2022-06-28T15:41:49.062385+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket" host=onlineauctionapi.herokuapp.com request_id=9a63da54-26fd-4c89-a96c-f21405cd08fe fwd="46.19.85.189" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30598ms status=101 bytes=202 protocol=https
2022-06-28T15:41:49.061409+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-28 15:41:49 +0000] [4] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:40)
2022-06-28T15:41:49.061951+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-28 15:41:49 +0000] [40] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 40)
2022-06-28T15:41:49.244258+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-06-28 15:41:49 +0000] [42] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 42
```

Comment: Self-signed server certificate?

Comment: Is this possible on the free version?

Comment: i asked whether you are using a self-signed certificate in your web server as node.js would refuse to connect to the server in this case without special setup

Comment: when it is regular api requests, it is working, also from a node.js server

Comment: I think you don’t get what I mean. When connecting to a local host, SSL encryption is handled differently (if you are connecting via SSL at all when connecting to your local machine). But when you try to connect to a remote machine, make sure the certificate is trusted or that you don’t require a trusted certificate. It’s just a guess, though

Comment: the flask api is working and has connection, but there is in socket a command of connect that is not working, so the SSL of the api is working through heroku, but the socket.io request of connection is not working. do you mean that the socket uses a different SSL then the regular api?

Comment: I mean that your node.js client seems not to accept the server's certificate and therefore refuses to connect. As I said before.

Comment: but is does accept, because on the same api, regular requests are working, thats why i mentioned that the regular requests are working

Comment: but the api is a different domain as far as I understand, isn’t it?

Comment: no, its the same one, but ill write it clearly in the question, thanks for the comment

Comment: Please update your post and include your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: @ChristopherTabula what do you mean update my post? include requirements.txt in the question?

Comment: @YakovBader What I meant is: Please include the contents of your `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the `eventlet` & `gevent` libraries, your `socketio.run(...)`
would have been enough for socket.io to work according to the [docs](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#embedded-server):

> If eventlet or gevent are available, socketio.run(app) starts a production-ready server using one of these frameworks.

However, you're deploying your app in heroku using Gunicorn as your web server, which requires additional commands to start `eventlet` or `gevent`. You have 2 options - both requiring update in your **Procfile**:

1. Using `eventlet`

```
web: gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 main:app
```

2. Using `gevent`

```
web: gunicorn -k gevent -w 1 main:app
```

You can read more about this [here](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment.html#gunicorn-web-server). Also, ensure that your `socketio.run(...)` does not have local settings.

Comment: both of them disable the rest of my api from working, but on the second option you gave me, the socket sometimes works when run is with `socketio.run(app, host='localhost', port=5000, debug=True)` and when it is  only `socketio.run(app)` it did not work yet for me

Comment: @YakovBader Import `os` in your flask app then, in your `socketio.run`, change the port to `int(os.environ.get('PORT', 33507))`. Finally, remove the `host='localhost'`.

Comment: by the way, the api is working, so i dont think the localhost is a problem, the only part of the api that is not working, is the socket

Comment: the socket still connects randomly and usually disconnects over and over again, and the rest of the api is not working